# Confusing perf stat results after multiple runs

Tags: linux, performance, caching, profiling, cpu-architecture

I executed a 1000x1000 matrix multiplication code consecutively 6 times along with *perf stat -e cache-misses* command and got the following results

```
Observation Cache-Misses Time elapsed(sec)
   1          48822173    7.697147087
   2          48663517    7.710045908
   3          48667119    7.701690126
   4          48867057    7.766267284
   5          48610651    7.701600681
   6          49203583    7.719180737
```

As we can see here, cache-misses for observation 1 is greater than cache-misses in observation 2,3 & 5. But the elapsed time for observation 1 is lesser than observation 2, 3 & 5. On the other hand observation 4 has highest elapsed time among all these observations but cache-misses for observation 4 is lesser than observation 3 and observation 6. According to the textbook, increasing cache-misses elongate the execution time of a program. Then how we can explain this behavior? Thanks

Here is my system details:

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    2
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 42
Stepping:              7
CPU MHz:               2300.000
BogoMIPS:              4589.89
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              3072K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several tools exist to find the root-cause of your cache misses. But a lot of misses does not always mean longer execution time. It depends also on cache-miss level.

Moreover, it is recommended to do one or two observations runs without collecting statistics to warm caches (i.e., filling them with data): subsequent runs will benefit from the first one which had warmed up the cache with necessary data.

A tool like [`dprof`](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/dprof/) can help you to find causes and performances problems due to cache-misses. Try it.

Comment: @.GHugo Thanks for your reply and the tool link! I believe cache-misses events in the perf tool counts the number of memory access due to misses in all levels of cache(in this case 3). So how these extra misses are not affecting the execution time? And why the 3rd, 4th and 6th observations are not getting advantage of already warmed up cache?

Comment: Without more information about your workload, you can not give explanation of the behaviour: is it multi-threaded/process ? where the matrix is stored ? (e.g., memory, file), etc. What I mean is cache-miss is not everything, you can have a lot of other performance hot-spot in your application. And cache-misses mesured by perf can also append in kernel, where a lot of different mechanisms take place and can affect the cache content. Give a try to dprof, it should help you to understand the cause of your cache misses.

Comment: perf has an option to capture only user-level cache misses: `perf stat -e cache-misses:u`. It can be interesting to see if the difference of cache misses is on kernel or user level code.

Comment: @.GHugo,Thanks for your explanation. I'll try dprof and perf with :u to see whats going on.